# CPU Time and CPU Usage

Tags: linux

Why does the CPU time increase while the process is running, but the CPU usage does not increase?
I have a process that throughout its run, the CPU time has increased, but the CPU usage has not changed.

Comment: How do you get the statistics? Which tool or service? What your process is doing?

Comment: `Why does the CPU time increase while the process is running, but the CPU usage does not increase?` Weell, most probably because CPU time divided by actual time spent running is constant. Is CPU time cumulative?